# How to prepare runnable jar for Open cv java project?

Tags: java, opencv

I have devloped one project for face detection using opencv **open cv 2.4.9** on windows. now i have to run the jar on ubuntu machine. i gets failed.

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no opencv_java249 in java.library.path
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1889)
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:849)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1088)
```

my main concern is how to prepare package (runnable jar) having opencv-249 dependency for ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

You should load the OpenCV lib pragmatically as below:

```
// get the model
String model = System.getProperty("sun.arch.data.model");
// the path the .dll lib location
String libraryPath = "C:/opencv/build/java/x86/";
// check for if system is 64 or 32
if(model.equals("64")) {
    libraryPath = "C:/opencv/build/java/x64/";
}
// set the path
System.setProperty("java.library.path", libraryPath);
Field sysPath = ClassLoader.class.getDeclaredField("sys_paths");
sysPath.setAccessible(true);
sysPath.set(null, null);
// load the lib
System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
```

You can run this method when the program starts.

Comment: and C:/opencv/build/java/x64/ referes to which file?  .dll or .so?if so then what is the process to do.

Comment: I have already you the path `C:/opencv/build/java/x64/` it the path to the .dll file of OpenCV, so when you extracted the OpenCV, the .dll file path should be like this `opencv/build/java/x64/` and `opencv/build/java/x86/`, so you can then put the opencv folder in C drive which become like this: `C:/opencv/build/java/x64/` for the 64 bit system, and C:/opencv/build/java/x86/ for 32 bit system.